# How To Print A Single Record from a Microsoft Access Form into a Report

Tags: database, vb.net, ms-access, ms-access-2003

i'm very new to Access and VB, and im about to print a specific record.. but im getting an error with this code:

```
Private Sub printEksternAVR_Click()
DoCmd.OpenReport [Report_AVR Ekstern], acViewPreview, , [Report_AVR Ekstern].Rapport_nr = Forms!Form_AVR

End Sub
```

My reports name is AVR Ekstern, and the prime key is Rapport nr and the form im clicking the button and viewing the record in, is AVR

i think i misunderstood something alon the way, so i really hope someone can help me out here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The WHERE condition is a string.  You'll need to wrap that parameter in quotes.  Assuming `Rapport_nr` is an Integer:

```
Private Sub printEksternAVR_Click()
DoCmd.OpenReport [Report_AVR Ekstern], acViewPreview, , "Rapport_nr = " & Forms!Form_AVR

End Sub
```

Er wait, you're also missing the field in Forms!Form_AVR which you're supposed to use as the key value placeholder in the query string.  You're just referencing the form itself there.  Add that form field name at the end there too, whichever field holds the key value you're looking up.

See: [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb243764%28v=office.12%29.aspx) for more details.

Comment: oh, btw, is there any way to "force" my report to print out the "layout" wven if the fields are empty, like in if i only filed some of the data but not all, it would stil print out my supreports? i have liek one report, which is allways there.. and 8-9 supreports where they not allways will be filled, but will be send out to a customer and filled manualy, and the send back ? is there any easy way of doing so? (manualy speaking of a doc,docx,dot,rtf or whatever they can write in - as NOT in pdf)

Comment: You mean if there's no data in those subreports, instead print empty boxes in place of all fields?  A certain control property comes to mind, but I can't think of it at the moment and I'm not near my windows machine to test it.  Not sure.